# LINQ group by not working

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I've read lots of group by replies in this forum, but I have to ask anyway:

```
var errandQuery = (from t in db.TimereportSet
                   group t by new { t.Errand.Name, t.Date } into g
                   select new ErrandTime { Date = g.Key.Date, Value = g.Sum(e => e.Hours) }).ToList();
```

why isn't this working. I get the following exception: `"Unknown column 'GroupBy1.K1' in 'field list'"`

the exception comes from the mySQLClient.

Comment: What is the generated SQL query? add a line `db.Log = Console.Out;` to log the query to the output window in Visual Studio.

Comment: This could be a provider (mySQLClient) bug.

Comment: My context doesn't have a .Log member?

Comment: I did this: 

Console.WriteLine(((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)errandQuery).ToTraceString());

SELECT
1 AS `C1`, 
`GroupBy1`.`K1` AS `Date`, 
`GroupBy1`.`A1` AS `C2`
FROM (SELECT
Sum(`Extent1`.`Hours`) AS `A1`
FROM `TimereportSet` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `ErrandSet` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`Errand_Id` = `Extent2`.`Id`
 GROUP BY 
`Extent1`.`Date`, 
`Extent2`.`Name`) AS `GroupBy1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not selecting Hours into g, so they aren't there to sum.

I don't know what your data looks like but try this:

EDIT:

```
var errandQuery = (from t in db.TimereportSet                    
                   group t by new { t.Errand.Name, t.Date } into g                   
                   select new ErrandTime { Date = g.Key.Date, Value = g.Sum**(t => t.Hours)** }).ToList();
```

Sorry, my first response was incorrect.

You LINQ query is correct, except right at the end --- you are using e..  where you need to reference the items you selected ... **so you would need to use t in your lambda expression instead of e**

Comment: You can't group on the hours if you want to sum them up per group.

Comment: Let's say `TimereportSet` is of type `IQueryable<T>`. Then `g` would be of type `IGrouping<a', T>`, which implements `IEnumerable<T>`. So `g.Sum(e => e.Hours)` should be correct, as long as `T` has a property `Hours`.

Comment: I think this is a bug in Linq to mySQL, is there another way of querying for the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this as a comment but it should be an answer, this is a confirmed bug in mySQL with LinQ. Is there another way of querying for the same thing using a work around, objectquery or direct sql or something else using the entity framework:

```
var errandQuery = (from t in db.TimereportSet
                   group t by new { t.Errand.Name, t.Date } into g
                   select new ErrandTime {
                       Date = g.Key.Date,
                       Value = g.Sum(e => e.Hours)}).ToList();
```

or should I create a new post for this question?